# How to reference Python airflow package in eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, airflow

I am completely new to `airflow` and `Cloud Composer`.
I used the command (in cmd prompt of Windows) `pip install apache-airflow-providers-google` to install the airflow packages on my local Windows laptop.
`pip list` shows that the packages are present:
[image]
Now I installed the `PyDev` plugin in my Eclipse to prepare some python scripts for **Google Cloud Composer**.
Now in my python file in Eclipse, when I type `import airflow`, it shows that **airflow** is unresolved.
However `import pandas` and `import datetime` etc are showing up alright.

[image]
How do I reference this **Airflow** package in my Eclipse ?
The reason I am doing this is to ease my coding effort, since IDEs predict the keywords, packages, and its functions easily, and reduces a lot of effort.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using VSCode for the development of dags, operator and sensors.
But a quick note, Pydev doesn't automatically rescan the site-packages folder. You need to go to `Preferences-> Interpreter -> Python` and click apply to make it scan again.

Comment: Welcome to SO, this is not answering to the question.